# divide + "into" or "in"

Tags: prepositions

I knew that we use the verb "`divide`" with `"into"` preposition when we want to say to be divided into parts:

> He divided a pear into two parts.

But, why in here we can also say (as I see here in Oxford):

> He divided a pear in two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it says [here](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9DuoA7PwRCZM.html), except for such phrases as *divide in half* and *divide in two*, the preposition *into* is used because *divide* emphasizes separating, breaking up or cutting up a whole into sections or parts, changing the state or form of something. When half and two are used as adjectives, the correct phrasing is *divide into*.

- The math teacher divided the apple **in two**.
- The math teacher divided the apple **into two parts**.
- Mother divided the pile of toys **in half**.
- The team’s activities were divided **into half days**.
- Shall we divide the project **into six** or **seven small tasks**?

Comment: According to most definitions, *divide into* would not be considered a phrasal verb because we can comprehend the meaning of the two words separately. We can understand *divide into* just as we can understand *jump into* or *divide over* as in something like *two things will divide over a period of time.* In contrast, we cannot understand the phrasal verb *wake up* by combining the separate meanings of the verb and the particle. In addition, something like *divide in parts* is perfectly grammatical.