# When to use "as"

Tags: as

I came across this sentence "This is what we would call a state of equilibrium." which is followed by some explanation and examples before.

I am wondering if we can also use "as" like below because we are justifying why we are calling this "a state of equilibrium."

"This is what we would call **as** a state of equilibrium."

Comment: No, but you could say "This is what we would *describe as* a state of equilibrium." *call* is just a word used to name something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the definitions of *as* at [this dictionary site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as), but with examples to demonstrate, I will show you that you can use the words *call* and *as* side by side in a sentence can be done as long as the *as* is used as

- an adverb
  used to emphasize an amount,

> sometimes she would **call as** much as twenty-two times an hour

- a conjunction used to indicate that something happens during the time when something else is taking place,

> Frank had a mobile phone **call as** he ambled through the crowd

- a conjunction used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done,

> As far as phone calls are concerned, they can **call as** they wish

- a conjunction used to add or interject a comment relating to the statement of a fact,

> I had to make that **call, as** you know

- a conjunction as in *because* or *since*,

> I must make that **call as** that is what is expected of me

- a preposition used to refer to the function or character in the role of, being, acting as, functioning as,

> I made that **call as** your manager

or

- a preposition in the form of during the time of being (the thing specified).

> She often made that **call as** a doctor

The word *call* is used in your sentence as a verb to designate the condition of something as being in the state of equilibrium.  You cannot use *as* in the form of a preposition after this verb but you can if *call* was a noun, as you can see from my examples above.

If you wish, you can refer to the [British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/verbs-prepositions) or [this website](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/verbs-and-prepositions.html) for information on using prepositions with verbs.

Comment: *She often made that call as a doctor* does not exemplify *during the time of being* so much as *in the capacity of; qua.*

Comment: See more detail on documenting resources in my comments on your answer to [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114194/divide-into-or-in)